# Finding the inverse of a natural log

Tags: logarithms

> How would I find the inverse of $$\ln(8x-64)?$$

I've tried put $8x-64$ as the power to the base of $e$, I don't know what to do from there on, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "inverse"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the inverse of the [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) $$f(x) = \ln(8x-64)$$

You want a function $g(y)$ such that $g\left(f(x)\right) = x$, so $$g\left(\ln(8x-64)\right) =x$$

This means $y = \ln(8x-64)$, so $$e^y = 8x-64$$

$$\frac{e^y + 64}{8} = g(y)$$

Answer (score 5):

Set, $y=\log(8x-64)$ and solve for x.

So , $$e^y=e^{\log(8x-64)}$$
 $$e^y=8x-64$$

You should be able to go from here.

Comment: Log is meant to be base e.